# Find the minimum value of $3 \sin 2x + 5$ and the value of x where this occurs in the interval $0\le x \le\pi$

Tags: trigonometry

Find the minimum value of $3 \sin 2x + 5$ and the value of x where this occurs in the interval $0\le x \le\pi$

Turning points occur where $\frac{dy}{dx} = 0$

$f'(x) = 3\cos 2x$

$3\cos 2x = 0$

$3(2\cos^2 x -1) = 0$

$6\cos^2 x -3 = 0$

$\cos^2 x =\frac{1}{2}$

$\cos x = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$

$x = 45^{\circ}$

$x = \frac{\pi}4$

i am not sure if this is correct or where to go from here

Comment: Your derivative is wrong, you must use the chain rule to differentiate $3\cdot \sin(\color{red}{2x}) + 5$.

Comment: Why do you take derivative? The lowest value of 3sin2x is obviously 0 in the given range.

Comment: No, it's not that easy. (http://i.stack.imgur.com/0JgWK.png). Taking the derivative is fine. First, search for all minima/maxima with $f'(x) = 0$, then explicitly check both sides of the boundaries (at $x=0$ and $x = \pi$).

Comment: @N.S.JOHN  The function $ \ 3 \ \sin 2x \ $ runs through its full range over the interval $ \ 0 \ \le \ x \ \le \ \pi \ $ , so the minimum is rather less than zero.

Comment: @RecklessReckoner You are right I didn't notice that.

Comment: As with the other problem you posted, the poser is just asking for ways to use your knowledge of the value of trigonometric functions.  You just need to know where sine is smallest over its period (since $ \ \sin 2x \ $ goes through all of its values in the given interval).

Answer (score 2):

For such a well known and well behaved function like $\sin 2x$ you don't need to take the derivative. Over the given range, from the graph provided by Maximillian the minimum value of $\sin 2x$ is $-1$ and you should be able to determine the value $x$.

Comment: I'm really confused by this, I thought yo need to find the derivative to find a minima

Comment: @dagda1 In general the derivative method is the way to approach the problem of finding the minimum of a function $f(x)$, though in particular cases it is easier to plot the function and see where $\frac{d f(x)}{dx} = 0$. Generally, you also have to look at the second derivative (for example for your case, there are other places where $\frac{d f(x)}{dx} = 0$, at these places the function is a *maximum*).

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to only use derivatives to solve that problem, it would go like this.

If we have 
$$f(x) = 3\sin(2x) + 5$$

Using the chain rule

$$(f \circ g)' = f'(g) \cdot g'$$

For deriving 
$$\sin(2x)$$

We get 
$$f(x) = \sin(x), \; g(x) = 2x$$
$$f'(x) = \cos(x), \; g'(x) = 2$$

And thus
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left( \sin(2x) \right) = 2\cos(2x)$$

Using straightforward differentiating methods we would now have

$$f'(x) = 6\cos(2x)$$
Solving for $0$ with $0 \leq x \leq \pi $ gives
$$\cos(2x) = 0 \Longleftrightarrow x= \pi/4 \; \lor x = 3\pi/4 $$
(either by looking at the graph or using $\cos^{-1}$)

For which we have the function values
$$f(\pi/4) = 8$$
$$f(3\pi/4) = 2 $$
And on the boundaries
$$f(0) = 5$$
$$f(\pi) = 5 $$
By which you should be able to tell that the minimum is at $x = 3\pi/4 \approx 2.356$, as the graph already showed.